# d3 Bar Graph: Trouble seeing my Graph. might be issue with append()

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js, svg

I'm trying to build a bar graph and I don't see anything on my html page when I load it on my local sever.

This is my java script:

```
var formatYear = d3.timeFormat("%Y");

var svg = d3.select('body').select('svg')
const width = d3.select('body').append('svg').attr('width');
const height = d3.select('body').append('svg').attr('height');

// create d3 data join

// load csv file
d3.csv('q3.csv').then(data => {
  data.forEach(d => {
    d.year = Date(+d.year, 1, 0); //parse data
    d.running_total = +d.running_total // parse data
  });
  render(data);
});

const render = data => {
  const xValue = d => d.running_total;
  const yValue = d => d.year;
  const xScale = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain([0, d3.max(data, d => d.running_total)])
    .range([0, d3.max(data, d => d.year)]);
  const yScale = d3.scaleBand()
    .domain(data.map(d => d.year))
    .range([0, height]);
  svg.selectAll('rect').data(data)
    .enter().append('rect')
    .attr('y', d => yScale(d.running_total))
    .attr('width', d => xScale())
    .attr('height', yScale.bandwidth())
};
```

I checked first to make sure my data is loaded properly and it is. I see it on the console. I think there's something wrong with my append.() function but I've googled extensively and they all seem to have the same concept:
1. You have an element (Rectangle in this case)
2. You have your data
3. append the data to the element

It seems like this part of the code is wrong but I can't seem to figure it out.

This is my html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Lego Sets by Year from Rebrickable</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/d3/d3.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <svg width='960' height='500'></svg>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="main1.js"></script>
  <h1>Lego Sets by Year from Rebrickable</h1>
  <P align=right>xxxxxxx <P>
</body>

</html>
```

Here's the first row of my csv file:

```
 year   running_total
1949    5
```

Comment: There is no SVG in your HTML. Therefore, this: `var svg = d3.select('body').select('svg')` is `null`.

Comment: I added the following under body: <svg id="svg" width='600' height='300'></svg> but I'm not getting anything. No errors though

Comment: please add example of 'q3.csv'

Comment: year running_total
1949 5

Comment: @altocumulus I'm able to parse the data. The issue is that I'm able to see the rectangles (elements) on my console but not on the web page. They have a height and width though.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Lego Sets by Year from Rebrickable</title>
</head>

<body>
  <svg width='960' height='500'></svg>
  <h1>Lego Sets by Year from Rebrickable</h1>
  <P align=right>xxxxxxx <P>
</body>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

  var formatYear = d3.timeFormat("%Y");

  var svg = d3.select("svg");            // Line 20
  const width = svg.attr('width');       // Line 21
  const height = svg.attr('height');     // Line 22

  // create d3 data join

  // load csv file
  d3.dsv(" ", "q3.csv").then(data => {       // Line 27
    data.forEach(d => {
      // d.year = Date(+d.year, 1, 0);       // Line 29
      // d.running_total = +d.running_total  // Line 30
    });
    render(data);
  });

  const render = data => {
    const xScale = d3.scaleLinear()
      .domain([0, d3.max(data, d => d.running_total)])
      .range([0, width]);                               // Line 38

    const yScale = d3.scaleBand()
      .domain(data.map(d => d.year))
      .range([0, height])
      .padding(0.1);                                    // Line 43

    svg.selectAll('rect').data(data)
      .enter().append('rect')
      .attr("x", 0)                                     // Line 47
      .attr('y', d => yScale(d.year))                   // Line 48
      .attr('width', d => xScale(d.running_total))      // Line 49
      .attr('height', yScale.bandwidth())

  };

</script>

</html>
```

Hi, I did some changes to your code.

1. Line 20-22, leave only one 'svg' element.
2. Line 29-30, no need for data parsing. If you need axis formatting, do it with [d3-axis](https://github.com/d3/d3-axis).
3. Line 38, fix `xScale`
4. Line 43, add padding to `yScale`
5. Line 47-49, fix `x`,`y`,`width` value of `rect`
6. Line 27, use [d3.dsv](https://github.com/d3/d3-fetch#dsv)

used csv:

```
year   running_total
1949   5
1950   6
1951   7
1952   8
```

[image: Result Screenshot]

Comment: Thank you for this. I'm getting frustrated as to why I'm not able to see the rectangles.

Comment: @user300 maybe you could open web console to see if there is any error or warning?